# How do I set common values (abstract) for a C# solution in Visual Studio with multiple sub projects?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, solution

I have a solution with multiple projects each of which connects to the same DB and uses overlapping constant values that I would like to set somewhere instead of replicating manually. I have tried a variety of things online like making a custom class and linking projects to it, setting constants in a project config file (which doesn't exist like the guides claim), and so on. I've been unable to figure this out after more than an hour of searching and experimenting so if you have any ideas, let me know. The structure looks like this (the blue-underlined stuff are some of the projects in the list):

[image: project listing in solution]

Comment: 1. Another project containing the common stuff -  2. A file added via "Add as Link" to all the projects  -  3. An XML or JSON file deployed to the app folder and read by all sub projects

Comment: Someone suggested adding the class "as a link" before, but there was no option for that that I could see. You're saying it would work i fit was a project?

Answer (score 4):

You can make another project under the solution to contain your class.

All the other projects can then reference that project, meaning the same functionality will be available in all the other projects without having to duplicate anything.

Comment: Reference how? I tried "using" and it doesn't see it.

Comment: With the "add reference" feature

Answer (score 1):

I will extend the previous correct answer with some more information.

Your solution structure is something to think very carefully as it is a combination of application design/architecture and leads to extensibillity, scalability and future maintainability.

Take for example the following article [Common web application architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures).

- You can see the Clean Architecture (AKA Hexagonal) which leads to specific projects withing a solution
- You can see older designs where the DB access would go into a project called ..DAL

Simple projects can use the second one, more business rich ones the first or something in between.

Check this [this article on shared code projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard?tabs=windows) to see about net standard projects

Answer (score 1):

So the above was helpful, but far more complicated than it needed to be. Apparently other answers I'd seen actually work, but it took reading a bunch of other pages to figure out the whole puzzle. The working steps are:

1. Create a class with public parameters for your constants
2. Place that class somewhere in your solution space. When I created it on the solution, it was placed in "Solution Items" in my tree (which is the root folder of the solution on the file system).
3. Right click each project and ADD>Existing Item and point to the class. The KEY (that was missing from most things I read) was that the "add" button" has a drop-down arrow that lets you change it to "Add as link"
4. In each project (after adding as link to the file), you can directly reference the values as NAMEOFCLASS.NAMEOFCONST but ONLY if you declared them as public const SOMETYPE SOMENAME. Without the const, it's not able to directly reference the value

Note that this fix is in the .sln file itself and needs to be part of the commit or it won't have any effect. It would be nice if you could use "include" or something to bring in a file a folder one level up, but here we are.

Comment: "Without the const" - also static will work.